# Odd behavior in material design

Tags: google-materials-design

I was reading through Google's material design spec on the topic of [elevation and shadows](https://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-shadows) (under the Shadows section), and it seems the button states are backwards.

It shows the *pressed* state with a deeper shadow indicating that it has a higher elevation, but if I'm pressing a button, shouldn't it have a lower elevation?

Comment: Interesting! The faded disabled color makes sense, but I see what you mean with the raised look as opposed to a pushed look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting. I'm also reading Google Material Design right now.

Anyway, I think there is another discussion with the same issue you are wondering, and Evil Closet Monkey has a really good answer about this. Take a look at [his answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/72829) to see if it has cleared your question.

Comment: Awesome link.  It also contains links to other answers addressing the same thing.  I tend to agree with the first comment on the answer you linked to: I disagree with Google's decision on this.  It seems that the default for a button would be raised so that when pressed the button could drop.

Comment: Then, it would go against the concept of the material design about paper. If the default for a button was raised just so it could drop on press, it would become kind of like 'floating', don't you think? A piece of paper cannot float on another piece of paper in real life. It's resting upon it, so the only way for it to go is up. I agree that it's odd. I also couldn't understand the concept at first.