# Mobile Button - When tapping (before releasing), should it grow or shrink?

Tags: mobile, user-behavior, user-expectation, mobile-application, usability-testing

I'm wondering, 
On Mobile, when pressing a button (before releasing the finger), should the button **grow or shrink**? After the user lift his finger, the button returns to normal state.

Illustration:

[image]

Comment: This question is asking about a common human-computer interaction method and affordances. This seems answerable and on topic. Though the answer may be "there is no standard," that is still a valid answer. For further discussion, I have posed a question about these situations [on Meta](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3221/when-to-close-as-primarily-opinion-based-in-lieu-of-an-answer) already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Both methods can work. **Shrinking** is more logical but has less visibility because of the user's finger. **Growing** is not corresponding to expectations of real life but the interaction is better visible.

---

Instinctically, I would always prefer a button to **shrink**, as you are **pressing it down** and that corresponds to the perception of the real world.
The only problem that can arise with this is that the **finger then covers the button** and the user can not see what happens to it anymore. So the growing method has the advantage of better visibility.

The [Google Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-shadows) mention **elevation** and how it helps the user understand the order of the UI elements.
They have one section that talks about [raised buttons](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html##buttons-raised-buttons) and these should **go up when pressed**. There is an interesting discussion about this here:
[Material design - buttons raise, not depress](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/72823/67657)
I personally do not agree with that decision as it comes off as totally counter-intuitive.

Here is another question that might be related to yours:
[Make people understand they can click on a button in a flat design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/69663/make-people-understand-they-can-click-on-a-button-in-a-flat-design)

---

In the end, **you can probably pull off both methods** as long as you design them appealing and understandable enough.

Answer (score 4):

Always prefer **Shrink** because by shrinking button, we are showing user that it is pressed. so for showing pressed effect, we should shrink button, it's a good practice and It's good for Ux.

For more information, you can check [this link](https://uimovement.com/ui/2649/writer/).

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying. Can you please provide resources or anything standing with this statement? Thank you!

Comment: @RoiMulia I have updated my answer.